# Large IN statement - data from spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
People
-----------------
email_address
created_date
```

I also have a spreadsheet with about 60,000 e-mail addresses in it. I need to select the "created_date" for each e-mail address in the spreadsheet. The way I am currently approaching it is to create one big select statement with an IN clause:

```
SELECT email_address, created_date FROM People WHERE email_address in (
'user1@something.com',
'user2@something.com',
'user3@something.com',
...
```

The problem with this is that it is a HUGE script (60,000+ lines) and I can't even get it to run due to errors like "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes" and "MSQL Server has gone away".

I might be able to fix those errors by increasing max_allowed_packet, etc., but I have a feeling that it might just be a symptom that my SQL sucks and instead of just treating the symptom, I should fix the problem and write better SQL. Let me know if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the email addresses into a separate, one column table and use

```
 SELECT email_address, created_date FROM People 
    WHERE email_address IN (SELECT email_address FROM email_table)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not strong in SQL, you mean write a large INSERT statement to insert into a temporary table? Or is there some other way to insert a large amount of data?

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to save the email column in the spreadsheet to a text file and load it as text or csv (albeit with only one column) using some MySQL admin program.  IIRC MySQL uses separate files for tables, so you can add and remove the table without any effect on the overall database.

Comment: OK, thanks. Actually, in this case, I need to create a script that I can just hand off to someone else to run elsewhere. In order to make it as easy as possible for them, I think I will try avoiding using any admin tools.

Comment: @Jason: To script it, check out the LOAD DATA command of MySQL — high speed load functionality.  (I mistakenly thought this was a one-off thing).

Comment: My fault, I should have been more clear. I will check that out, thank you so much for the help. I will most likely mark this as the answer once I try this out.

Comment: No worries, just happy to be of help.  And your question wasn't unclear, I just made an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: I ended up writing an insert statement similar to what ring0 described in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create first an Addresses table, including an index

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses (addr char(255) primary key);
```

Insert the addresses in a script

```
INSERT INTO Addresses VALUES ('address1'),('address2'),...;
```

You can break down the insertion if necessary (big script)

```
INSERT INTO Addresses VALUES ('address1'),('address2');
INSERT INTO Addresses VALUES ('address3'),('address4');
...
```

Then you can easily and quickly search the People table

```
SELECT p.email_address, p.created_date 
FROM People as p JOIN Addresses as a ON p.email_address=a.addr;
```

Comment: I did end up using sql like this. However, I needed to maintain the original order of insert so I did not declare the "addr" column so I did not create that column as an index.